# Get files with rights rw to all users

Tags: shell

I've tried

```
ls -l | cut -f1 d" " | grep ".{4}rw.{4}"
```

For example

```
drwxrwx--x folder folder 4096 sep 3 19:01 dir2
```

I cut off first column and find match with "rw"

But nothing happens

Comment: Your title says all, but your attempt seems to be looking at group permissions...

Comment: Take a look at the `find` command. Parsing the output of `ls` always leads to sorrow.

Comment: 1. you are looking for group 'rw' permissions, so maybe you need {6} instead of {4}, also you should add -P option to grep to enable perl regexp: ls -l | cut -f1 -d" " | grep -P ".{6}rw"

Comment: I gotta take filenames. And your method is aleady used

Comment: Oh, with `zsh`, `printf "%s\n" *(f+030)` for all files with at least group read and write permissions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When searching for files by name, size, or other properties you can't go wrong with `find`. For your use case try `-perm -{mode}`, which finds files with all of the `{mode}` bits set. You can use a numeric mode like `030` or the symbolic version, `g=rw`:

```
find * -perm -g=rw                 # search subdirectories
find * -maxdepth 0 -perm -g=rw     # current directory only
```

Here's the full description of the different `-perm` options from the [find(1) man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html):

> ```
> -perm mode
>        File's permission bits are exactly mode (octal or
>        symbolic).  Since an exact match is required, if you want
>        to use this form for symbolic modes, you may have to
>        specify a rather complex mode string.  For example `-perm
>        g=w' will only match files which have mode 0020 (that is,
>        ones for which group write permission is the only
>        permission set).  It is more likely that you will want to
>        use the `/' or `-' forms, for example `-perm -g=w', which
>        matches any file with group write permission.  See the
>        EXAMPLES section for some illustrative examples.
>
> -perm -mode
>        All of the permission bits mode are set for the file.
>        Symbolic modes are accepted in this form, and this is
>        usually the way in which you would want to use them.  You
>        must specify `u', `g' or `o' if you use a symbolic mode.
>        See the EXAMPLES section for some illustrative examples.
>
> -perm /mode
>        Any of the permission bits mode are set for the file.
>        Symbolic modes are accepted in this form.  You must
>        specify `u', `g' or `o' if you use a symbolic mode.  See
>        the EXAMPLES section for some illustrative examples.  If
>        no permission bits in mode are set, this test matches any
>        file (the idea here is to be consistent with the behaviour
>        of -perm -000).
> ```

Comment: Thank you for a helpful answer. But I gotta use ls, pipe, grep